# android WebView support JSP or not?

Tags: android, jsp, android-webview

In my project I am using WebView that show all page but not load this page,

https://sarathi.nic.in:8443/nrportal/sarathi/Browser/Help_LLNew.html

Need to know `android WebView` support JSP?

Comment: Please include the code that you are using to display the webpage

Answer (score 0):

webview is a container based on chromium

technically it's not dependent on the server side technology being used

more detail [here](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview)

I was recently involved in a project that had an android counter part app opening the whole website in a webview as an extension of the app functionality - it worked fine through iframes and payment gateway and responsive layouts using bootstrap -

Answer (score 0):

Maybe enabling javascript will do the trick.
You can do it like this

```
yourWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```